# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, sessionfactory

This error is occuring with Hibernate 3.2 and resolved by using `ServiceRegistryBuilder`
This is my code:

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Sam");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
          }
     }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider: Provider org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorBuilder.buildSelector(StrategySelectorBuilder.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
```

This was the error while executing the hibernate framework with wrong api's.
This problem was resolved by changing my code like this:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
public class HibernateTest {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Sam");
     if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
            registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();  
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

This was the code.

Comment: I am getting this error, how to resolve it?

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to enter the data in MYsql using hibernate and getting this error.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @SuperbSaif your code should go into the question as an edit.  Not a comment.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the "edit" button to update your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different version of Hibernate. Probably 4 and above. According to guideline you should use following syntax

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/building-hibernate-sessionfactory-from-service-registry

Comment: Thanks, working fine now!!!!

Comment: I was facing the same error @SuperbSaif