# Error while connecting Mysql db with java using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I was trying to connect a simple java application with mysql db using hibernate. I have already created the schema in my db and this java application is simply creating a table in this schema and inserting data in it.All the time I am getting same error.
My Code is as follows:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

**[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]**

**UserDetails.java**

[image]

**HibernateTest.java**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

Please help me, I have been stuck for quite a long time.

Thanks !!

Comment: There are not serious problems with stuff are showed by you. Please, add your libraries list.

Comment: Please post the code and error messages as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853341/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-serviceconfigurationerror)

Seems that your using hibernate >=4 and the setup procedure from hibernate <4.
Correct way according to the link is.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: I am not able to find any class named "ServiceRegistryBuilder".

Comment: What's your hibernate version.

Comment: thanks ! this worked for hibernate 4 , but still shows same error for hibernate % release.

Comment: Take a look into the hibernate 5 documentation -> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/

Comment: @SuyashTilhari `new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();` is the correct way of Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 configuration. Why do you accept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
//check External Jar files whether you added properly or not...if not remove all jar files and add once again...
```

> After Main

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.OpenSession();
UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
ud.setName("bdskbf");
ud.setId(23);
Transaction tnx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(ud);
tnx.getTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: `cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");` does  the same as `cfg.configure();` does. `sf.OpenSession();` is incorrect, as you know :)